# On a whim vs. at the whim

Tags: prepositions, articles, idioms

> We bought a house on a whim.
>
> My duties seem to change daily at the whim of the boss.

These are correct sentences but would they be gramattically correct if I switched on and at?

> We bought a house at a whim.
>
> My duties seem to change daily on the whim of the boss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

> on a whim

refers to the whim of the person involved

> I went away for the weekend it *on a whim*.
>   She bought the handbag *on a whim*.
>   *On a whim* we bet everything on red.

Whereas

> at the whim

refers to a third person

> The course changed direction *at the whim* of the skipper.
>   The leaves swirled *at the whim* of the changing wind.
>   Our winnings were *at the whim* of the roulette ball.